# dependencies is not working in jsonschema validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Below is my json schema compatible to jsonschema 4.0.

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { 
        "type": "number" ,
        "id":"credit_card"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "type": "string" ,
        "id":"billing_address"
    }
},
"required": ["name"],
"dependencies": [{
    "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
}]

}
```

`dependencies` is not working there i.e. whenever credit_card details are given, generated form should ask for billing_address as well. Fields are shown properly though but no validation error is shown when credit_card details are filled in.
[image]

We have enabled validation on `interaction`
Am I doing it wrong or there is some version issue. Notice I haven't specified $schema for now.

Any helps?

Comment: did you check schema version? I guess this should be working for jsonschema 4.x

Comment: yes! I have mentioned though in my schema i just didn't specify schema and hence it should be taking up the latest one i guess

Comment: Vinay, Jason's answer is correct as per the spec for dependencies https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wright-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependencies` should not be wrapped in an array.  Change your `dependencies` to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "credit_card": ["billing_address"]
}
```

That will make your schema valid, but that is no guarantee that the form generator you are using supports the `dependencies` keyword.  Often they only support a subset of the JSON Schema spec.